# Sound Visualizer for Wave Files in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio

My program currently plays a .wav file using MediaElement in wp7.

I want to write a extremely simple visualizer for it (for example a number that indicates the amplitude of the wave). However I have no idea on how I should obtain the raw media information from the `MediaElement`.

I have searched around, and so far have ended up with the Salus MediaKit (only for MP3), Beat detection (which involves complex algorithms) and WaveControl, which does not display in real time.

Could someone more well versed in audio processing point me towards a approach I could take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can obtain the raw audio data from the media element. Need access to the audio file ahead of time to do your calculations and then use GetSampleAsync of the MediaStreamSource class to send audio samples to your MediaElement. Can find documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource.getsampleasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Think you can still use the Saluse Media Kit as a reference as it is first decoding the mp3 file into raw audio data and then doing its operations on that. Can look in the RawMP3MediaStreamSource class to reference this. WAV files are uncompressed, so you should be able to calculate your amplitude from it after you strip out any header information. A good thing to read is how [uncompressed audio (PCM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM) is stored.